# How to interpolate lines over nans in pylab?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

Pylab inserts line breaks where there are nans in the data. How can I get continuous lines. I think matlab does this automatically.

example:

```
x = linspace(0,1,10)
y = rand(10,2)
y[5:8,1] = nan
plot(x,y,'.-')
```

I want `y[:,1]` interpolated but not `y[:,0]` since there are no points missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select the rows without `nan`

```
from pylab import isnan
boolind = ~isnan(y).any(1)
```

then do

```
plot(x[boolind], y[boolind])
```

if you want a value from linear interpolation to substitute that `nan`, you simply record the position of that `nan` and do the interpolation using adjacent points, but I think for plotting purposes, simply eliminating `nan` data points is enough - the code will do the linear interpolation for you anyway.

btw: presumably your `y = rand((10, 50))` should be `y = rand(10, 50)`, although I am not sure why you wanna plot a 2D array against a 1D.

**EDIT**

for your particular question, you can simply plot the two columns of `y` separately

```
from pylab import *
x = linspace(0,1,10)
y = rand(10,2)
y[5:8,1] = nan
boolind = ~isnan(y)
plot(x[boolind[:,0]],y[boolind[:,0], 0],'.-')
plot(x[boolind[:,1]],y[boolind[:,1], 1],'.-')
show()
```

[image]

Comment: This deletes rows in which there is any number of nans leading to throwing away non-nan point. I'll clean up my question a bit ... still haven't got a clean way of doing this

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I ended up finding ... plotting separately works. Maybe that's the desired behavior when data is missing?

Comment: personally I never plot a 2d array against a 1d, coz I want to have full freedom to manipulate each curve separately, including the scenario you encountered - missing data/selective plotting.